# Connecting a router

Tags: router, ip, wan

I am trying to set up a new Tenda wifi router, but am having trouble. I am getting the following message: [image]

Does anyone know what this means? Also do I really need to set up the router if I'm already connected and I don't care about what the name or passord is?

Comment: You're getting answers that make assumptions about your network connections.  Why don't you describe your existing network configuration and how you have connected this WiFi router to produce the error message in order to receive approriate answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an IP address range conflict - the WAN port on the router is being plugged into a network and is getting/has an IP address in the same range its trying to use on the LAN.

(Depending on the way your network is set up, and what you are trying to achieve) the easiest course of action would be to modify the LAN range on your router do it is not in 192.168.x.x. - yYou might want to replace 192.168 with 10.0 for the LAN router.

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting the WAN Port of the Router to your network. Then you are trying to use the network IP as the Wi-Fi subnet. That is why you have the message.

Two options:

1. Use the WAN connection, set up DHCP on the Wireless Router and have a separate subnet. That works fine.
2. 

(a) Hook up a LAN port on the Wireless router to your network.

(b) Give the Wireless Router a static IP on your network.

(c) Turn DHCP OFF on the Wireless router.

Now your Wireless Router will get IP addresses from the Main Network. This is probably what you want and this works very well also. This (2) is how I hooked up my own home office network.